# Displaying Change need information

Tags: java

I need to write a java program that computes what bills and change will be given for a sales transaction.

It can only dispense 20s, 10s, 5s, 1s, quarters, dimes, nickles, and pennies.

If it doesnt have to dispense a denomination (say your change is 50 cents, it should only dispense two quarters.  It should make no mention of the other currency)

I can't get it to dispense the correct amount of currency, it just dispense all currencies (so for example, if it was $21 and I gave the cashier 22, the codes telling me to give .013 $20s, .294 $10s, ect.)
 If anyone can help me out that would be great.

```
double price;  // declares how much the price is
double moneyGiven; // declares how much money the cashier is given
int change; // declares how much change is given in return

System.out.println("Enter the Price of the item:");
price = IO.readDouble()*100; 
{
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the Amount Given:");
        moneyGiven = IO.readDouble()*100; 
        {
            if (moneyGiven > price) 
                System.out.println("Your Change is:");

            change = moneyGiven - price;
            int twenties = change / 2000;
            if (twenties >= 1) {
                change = change % 2000;
                System.out.println(twenties + "$20 Bills"); 
            }

            int tens = change / 1000;
            if (tens >= 1) {
                change = change % 1000;
                System.out.println(tens + "$10 Bills"); 
            }

            int fives = change / 500;
            if (fives >= 1) {
                change = change % 500;
                System.out.println(fives + "$5 Bills"); 
            }

            int ones = change / 100;
            if (ones >= 1) {
                change = change % 100;
                System.out.println(ones + "$1 Bills"); 
            }

            int quarters = change / 25;
            if (quarters >= 1) {
                change = change % 25;
                System.out.println(quarters + "Quarters"); 
            }

            int dimes = change / 10;
            if (dimes >= 1) {
                change = change % 10;
                System.out.println(dimes + "Dimes"); 
            }

            int nickles = change / 5;
            if (nickles >= 1) {
                change = change % 5;
                System.out.println(nickles + "Nickles"); 
            }

            int pennies = change / 1;
            if (pennies >= 1) {
                change = change % 1;
                System.out.println(pennies + "Pennies"); 
            }




            if (moneyGiven <= price) 
                System.out.println("Not enough!");

            if (moneyGiven == price) 
                System.out.println("There is no Change to be given.");

        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the *exact* inputs and results for your example. If the price is $21, what is the value that ends up in `price`? There are a number of possible failure points here and we need more information.

Comment: Here is an example return:

Enter the Price of the item:
21.32
Enter the Amount Given:
22
Your Change is:
0.136$5 Bills
0.68$1 Bills
2.72Quarters
1.8Dimes
1.6Nickles
3.0Pennies

Comment: There are ... a lot of issues. Are you using a proper IDE? If not, you need one. Automated bracket alignment will help with seeing scope. For example, you have `if (moneyGiven <= price)` inside the scope of `if (moneyGiven > price)`. It executes as written because of all the `if();` statements (semicolon), but when those are fixed it will never execute.

Comment: Updated with current code

Comment: re: my edit -- I reviewed a proposed edit and fixed only the indentation -- there are still issues with the code and syntax.

Answer (score 1):

A few things wrong here:

1. You have semi-colons after your `if` statements. This will mean the following code in braces is always executed
2. You seem to check if the remainder is greater than 0 from 5's onwards, rather than one.
3. You're output for each denomination is the result of the division, which may be a decimal. You need to output the floor of this.

Comment: OK I removed the semi-colons, however, when I enter a value that is less than the amount required it doesnt return the NOT ENOUGH, same with the statment that should read NO CHANGE NECESSARY.

I am not sure what you mean by number 2.  How is the remainder check wrong if I need to display pennies.

How would I output the floor of the division, or even enter a floor.  I was thinking of using loops instead but I am not sure how to setup a loop for this problem.

Comment: Ah, you also have a misplaced bracket. Your current code reads as follows:

if (moneyGiven > price) {
  ...
  if (moneyGiven <= price)
  if (moneyGiven == price)
}

Comment: THanks, fixed that bracket. Still having errors though when returning answers.  Here's an example of an exact return:
Enter the Price of the item:
21.32
Enter the Amount Given:
21.32
0.0$5 Bills
0.0$1 Bills
0.0Quarters
0.0Dimes
0.0Nickles
0.0Pennies
Not enough!
There is no Change to be given.

Comment: You have if (twenties >= 1) and if (tens >= 1) which is correct, and if (fives > =0) which should be if (fives >=1)

Comment: OOOH GOOD CALL!  Didn't see that.  That Partially solved it, it no longer is displaying unused amounts, however, its still displaying decimals for answers, I am going to try changing them from Doubles to ints.  Unless you think theres a better way of doing that.  -- strike that, you can't do that since you cant have an int=double.  Need some advice :(((

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer, but it's returning answers as decimaled answers, ie. 1.0, 5.0.  How would I get it to return answers without the .0?
However, I would like any input on my code:

```
    double price;  // declares how much the price is
    double moneyGiven; // declares how much money the cashier is given
    double change; // declares how much change is given in return

    System.out.println("Enter the Price of the item:");
    price = IO.readDouble()*100; {


    {


    System.out.println("Enter the Amount Given:");
    moneyGiven = IO.readDouble()*100; {




    if (moneyGiven > price) 


    System.out.println("Your Change is:");

    change = moneyGiven - price;
    double twenties = change / 2000;
    if (twenties >= 1) {
    change = change % 2000;
    System.out.println(Math.floor(twenties) + "$20 Bills"); }

    double tens = change / 1000;
    if (tens >= 1) {
    change = change % 1000;
    System.out.println(Math.floor(tens) + "$10 Bills"); }

    double fives = change / 500;
    if (fives >= 1) {
    change = change % 500;
    System.out.println(Math.floor(fives) + "$5 Bills"); }

    double ones = change / 100;
    if (ones >= 1) {
    change = change % 100;
    System.out.println(Math.floor(ones) + "$1 Bills"); }

    double quarters = change / 25;
    if (quarters >= 1) {
    change = change % 25;
    System.out.println(Math.floor(quarters) + "Quarters"); }

    double dimes = change / 10;
    if (dimes >= 1) {
    change = change % 10;
    System.out.println(Math.floor(dimes) + "Dimes"); }

    double nickles = change / 5;
    if (nickles >= 1) {
    change = change % 5;
    System.out.println(Math.floor(nickles) + "Nickles"); }

    double pennies = change / 1;
    if (pennies >= 1) {
    change = change % 1;
    System.out.println(Math.floor(pennies) + "Pennies"); }




    if (moneyGiven <= price) 
    System.out.println("Not enough!");

    if (moneyGiven == price) 
    System.out.println("There is no Change to be given.");

    }
        }
    }
    }

}
```